# Set individual character/words to different font in Vim(e.g increase the font size of first word of a sentence)

Tags: vim

In Vim, we can set the different fonts with command:

```
set guifont=Courier_New:h12:cANSI
```

I would like to know whether we can set different font like color highlight

```
syn match MyKeyboard /board\w\+/
highlight Mykeyboard guifg=Green
```

Answer (score 0):

The content and the title of your question don't really match.

Anyway… No, it's impossible to use more than one single font and one single font size at a time. The best you can get is Bold or Italic but it only works reliably in GUI Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in GVIM:

```
:highlight Mykeyboard guifg=Green font=Fixedsys
```

See `:help highlight-font`. All fonts used must still be monospaced and have the same size, as GVIM has fixed-width display cells. Using a larger font will cause redrawing problems!

Comment: Does it work for you? I doesn't for me in MacVim and GVim on Ubuntu.

Comment: @romainl: The GVIM 7.4 (GTK-Gnome2)from Ubuntu 13.10 doesn't work for me, neither, but GVIM 7.3 and 7.4 on Windows do work.

Comment: Hmm, would it be a Windows-only feature?

Comment: @romainl: No, the help mentions the X11 font name, and special features for Motif and Athena. Dunno why it doesn't work on GTK2; would need to ask on vim_dev.